# How to publish a .Net Core Web Api from VS Code to Azure?

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services

I'm starting with some examples on how to create a .Net Core Web Api in Visual Studio Code and everything is working fine locally :)

Now, I would like to publish the Web Api to Azure using VS Code.

1. Is that possible?
2. If so, can that be done using the UI? or command line/ third party tool?

From Visual Studio 2015 I know how to do that. Just wondering if we can do the same from VS Code.

any help would be very appreciated

Comment: This document may be helpful:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-azure-webapp-using-cli?tabs=windows

Answer (score 2):

> If so, can that be done using the UI? or command line/ third party tool?

The [Azure App Services extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.vscode-azureappservice) for VS Code lets you quickly browse, create, manage, and deploy Azure App Service websites.

[image]

Comment: "*Create new web apps/deployment slots (Linux with Node.js only)*" A+ for irony.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the following tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/publishing-with-visual-studio-code

As @Tom Sun - MSFT said, there are plugins. I recomend you to install the following:

- .NET Core Extension Pack
- Azure App Service